# PSSession as logged in user

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

I'm trying to setup a Powershell script that will monitor a VirtualBox VM (i.e, "Builder4") running on one of our build servers. It occasionally loses connection and I already have a script (local on the server) that reloads the network adapter, but I want to make it fully automated.

I have the PSSession correctly authenticated with the server, successfully connected, and I can run commands from the server, do an interactive session (Enter-PSSession), etc. However, it's a "new" session, so I can't manage any of the already running VMs.

The server setup is a Windows Server 2012 box with a single account. The account is local to the server as opposed to being on the corporate domain ("pc-name\user" vs. "company.na.com\user") and remains logged on as long as the server is running. Typically we connect to the server via RemoteDesktop. Even though I'm connecting to the PSSession using the same pc-name, username, and credentials, it does not appear to be connecting to the existing login on the server, although my only supporting evidence of this is that `VBoxManage list runningvms` returns an empty list. For example, running the following (basic contents of "test.ps1"):

```
whoami
VBoxManage list vms
echo -----
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

gives the following output:

#### From remote session

```
PS ...> test.ps1
win-*******\jenkins
"Builder1" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder2" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder3" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder4" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder5" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder6" {vm-hash-code}
-----
PS ...>
```

#### From server (locally)

```
PS ...> test.ps1
win-*******\jenkins
"Builder1" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder2" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder3" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder4" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder5" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder6" {vm-hash-code}
-----
"Builder1" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder2" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder3" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder4" {vm-hash-code}
"Builder5" {vm-hash-code}
PS ...>
```

As the `whoami` suggests, I appear to be logged in under the proper account/user. However, as the `VBoxManage list runningvms` suggests, Windows is seeing it as a "different user" (since `runningvms` are user-specific).

Is there anyway to connect to the existing login without logging it out and re-logging in with the CLI? Remote Desktop appears to work by just switching session control whenever a new Remote session is initiated (or unlocked at the physical machine), so I would imagine this functionality exists.

To finish and clarify, I need to remotely connect via CLI to the existing logged in session **not** just an existing user. So far I have no been able to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers from [Ulfy](https://serverfault.com/a/861394/410332) and [Cory Knutson](https://serverfault.com/a/861551/410332) managed to point me in the right direction to find a solution that fit my needs.

Unfortunately, starting the VMs with PSSession isn't an option as we still need to be able to graphically access them fairly often. I had attempted starting one of the VMs through the PSSession which did succeed, but was not physically accessible through the Remote Desktop or local login (a.k.a. the "login session") to the server.

Along the same lines, I tried using PSExec, which I discovered had the option to run under a specific session (obtainable through `query session`). I was able to start one of the VMs under the same session ID as the login session. I could only tell this by checking `tasklist` and seeing it listed under that session ID as it never visually appeared.

Ultimately, I ended up incorporating a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33488610/4739755) into the script I was writing. The used snippet creates a scheduled task for a designated user on the remote machine, runs it, and then removes the task. A bit hacky indeed, as the answer author states, but it works well for what I need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

PSSession uses WinRM to execute PS commands on a remote server. The session here is simply that established session, and has nothing to do with RD sessions.

If you need to extract variable info unique to a running RD/terminal session, you could look into PSExec.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to restate some of the existing information, but hopefully this can clear thing up.

Your problem is not that the script is seeing the PSSession as a different user. It is that Windows is session-based when it comes to remote connections. One user may have multiple sessions on one server, with separate processes that cannot interact with each other easily. There are some tools that can reach between sessions, which is needed to interact with system services running in session 0. These sessions are isolated for security purposes. Remote desktop will connect to your running session to allow you to manage the running VMs.

A PSSession is not a full interactive login either. It does not create a full windows "Session". You can see what I am talking about by using `tasklist` or `query session` from inside your PSSession. You will see session 0 and another session id for the console, but none for your PSSession. It also shows an arrow next to the session your are currently in. When in a PSSession, it will be the `services` session.

Now to be able to get your VMs to show up remotely, you could try starting them from inside the PSSession. Then, you could connect later and check into them, while reconnecting to the console session.